# UITableView animation issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation

I have a table on a page, but it doesn't take up the entire screen (about 1/3). At some point I would like to show something above the table, but keep the view below the table as it is.

This isn't really the problem though. I use a UIView animation to change the size of the table's frame and move it down. The issue is that when the animation starts the table loses the last few rows - the rows that would be hidden when the animation is complete.

Does anyone know a way around this?

I'd prefer to keep the table at the top of the view layers, so obscuring it and keeping it the same size for the duration of the animation wouldn't really work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your parent UIView set to a fixed size? When you move the table down, if the containing frame isn't also grown to accommodate the new height, that could be clipping your lower table cells.

Comment: No, there was ample space. I don't think that I described it properly though - when the table was growing it would grow to be bigger than it originally was, but the blank cell would appear in the table that was smaller than the original. If that makes sense... so the cell that was on the border of the original table's side would be blank, even though it was still visible.